# Azure VM keeps restarting

Tags: azure

I created an Azure vm running windows 10 pro. Everytime I sign into it with RDM the virtual machine says "you are being logged out. Windows will restart in 1 minute"

I tried turning off automatic updates and autoshutdown and that didn't help.

I also tried creating two different vms and the same thing happened.

Comment: What is "RDM" in this context?

Comment: The "you are being logged out. Windows will restart in 1 minute" message suggests that some critical Windows system process has been terminated, so Windows (almost) gracefully shuts-down to protect itself. This can happen with some kinds of malware infections... you _are_ running a firewall on that VM and not exposing it directly to the Internet, right?

Comment: No firewall and open to the internet. Im really new to this stuff. I will try installing a firewall.

Comment: Remote Desktop. Trying to login long enough to install steam and parsec.

Comment: "No firewall and open to the internet. Im really new to this stuff. " - wow...